# How to get with MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter a Json with Pascal casing?

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

Here is the thing... i'm using jtable (jquery) to show some user data. This component needs a json with two fields: Result and Records. In my controller i have a method to return the json:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/getUsersInJson")
 public @ResponseBody String getUsersInJsonHandler(){
     ElementsInList<User> users = new ElementsInList<User>();
     users.setItems(userService.getUsers());
     return users;
 }
```

The class ElementsInList contains two fields: result and records. Result is a string to get the success message and records is a parametrized list which contains in this case a list of users. I get this JSON:

"{"result":"OK","records":[{"username":"john",

But i need this:

"{"Result":"OK","Records":[{"username":"john",...

This is my Mapping:

```
<!-- Json converter bean --> 
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
        <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

How can i do it? I've checked some posts but have old versions.
I'm using Spring 3, Spring MVC and jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using JsonProperty annotation. You can give the name that jackson will use to build the json field. Here there is an example with jtable (jquery):

```
public class ElementsInList<T> {
    @JsonProperty("Result")
    private String result = "OK";

    @JsonProperty("Records")
    private List<T> records;
    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }
    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
    public List<T> getRecords() {
        return records;
    }
    public void setRecords(List<T> records) {
        this.records = records;
    }
}
```

The result json is this: {"Result":"OK","Records":[{"roleName":"admin"...

But there is more about this annotations. Check the api for more info: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/package-summary.html